# Javascript three async task waiting each other

Tags: javascript, async-await

I want to create a loop for three different methods. I've created example methods.

```
async function method1() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 2000);
  })
}

async function method2() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
  })
}

async function method3() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
  })
}
```

First of all, I need to run method1() and if the response is 'ok'. I want to run all of the three methods, but they should not wait for each other. How can I achieve this? In the below code, you can see they will wait for each other.

```
const method1Response = await method1();

if (method1Response == 'to something') {
  // run method2() in every 2 seconds.
  await method2();

  // run method3() in every 5 seconds
  await method3();
  
  // run method1() in every 3 seconds.
  await method1();
}
```

Comment: Maybe `Promise.all()` can help.

Comment: No they will wait each other they should be indepent

Comment: Hence, promise.all() will dispatch all of its promises at the same time. and then resolve once all of them are finished, so you can continue the promise chain after. The order in which the promises inside the .all() resolve won't matter.